# How can I get autoremove to actually remove things?

Tags: apt, uninstall, disk-usage, removing

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.  I want to clean out the /usr/src directory, but didn't want to do it manually using the advice here -- [Safe to remove /usr/src/linux-headers after purging older linux images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253048/safe-to-remove-usr-src-linux-headers-after-purging-older-linux-images) .  However, running the suggested answer in there ("autoremove") doesn't go anything

```
(env) myusername@chicommons-laboratory:/var/www/html/web$ ls /usr/src
linux-headers-4.15.0-88  linux-headers-4.15.0-88-generic  linux-headers-4.15.0-96  linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic
(env) myusername@chicommons-laboratory:/var/www/html/web$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-pc-bin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2987 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 115962 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing grub-pc-bin (2.02-2ubuntu8.14) ...
```

However, the files remain ...

```
(env) myusername@chicommons-laboratory:/var/www/html/web$ ls /usr/src
linux-headers-4.15.0-88  linux-headers-4.15.0-88-generic  linux-headers-4.15.0-96  linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic
```

and my disk space is unchanged.

Comment: `autoremove` has removed `grub-pc-bin` but you are looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: What about all that garbage in /usr/src ?  Do I need all that stuff?

Comment: Do you understand what that 'garbage' is used for? Do you know what kernel you are running?